Metastability concern in bang-bang phase detector
Background
The following is take from page 413 from Razavi's CMOS PLL book.

This section (13.4.1) discusses bang-bang phase detector. As highlighted in the picture above, it mentions that Dout might be metastable, and indicates that the metastability effect is analyzed in the article Analysis and modeling of bang-bang clock and data recovery circuits. The picture below shows the relevant part of the article.

It seems that the article focuses on the analog aspect of the metastable output, as how the non-full-level output affects the V/I converter and VCO, in the context of CDR. But my question regarding the metastability effect is more focusing on digital aspects.
My question
For example, the following is taken from Understanding Jitter and Phase noise:

The highlighted part ("PD Logic") takes 3 input (Dn+1, Dn, B). It seems that most likely B will be in metastable status, when the PD is locked (B aligns with the data transitions). My question is, how PD Logic handles such situations when B is metastable?
ps: note that although in the diagram above, the "PD Logic" drives a charge pump, my question is not for such PLL-related context, but in a context where the bang-bang PD is used to adjust the data sampling point (via a phase-rotator, e.g.) such that the rotated phase points to the data center for proper sampling. In this case, how the phase rotator handles possible metasable output of the bang-bang PD? A example is shown in page 115 of high speed serdes devices and applications, and in page 117 it concludes that:

The digital INC/DEC signals are then used to control the sampling phase of the clocks driving the Data/Edge latches. There are several popular schemes to digitally control the sampling phase, including phase rotators, PLLs, DLLs, and digital oversampling schemes. The HSS EX10 core utilizes a phase rotator-based CDR.

Basically it seems that the context assumes that the bang-bang PD outputs are digital, and the digital outputs also drive digital blocks. That's what I meant by "digital aspect" of the metastability effects of banb-bang PD outputs.

Wow   I have seen the first simple D ff circuit  when I had thick hair .I was too scared to use it ,fear of jitter .


My question is, how PD Logic handles such situations when B is metastable?

It depends what you mean by 'handle'. It doesn't really handle, as in 'do something sensible', it just behaves, as in 'this is what it does'.
The metastability itself just results in a reduction of gain around the lock point. On average, some transitions cause metastability, and so a prolongation of the output settling. With an integer loop this is rarely a problem. If manifest at all, it looks like an increase in the noise floor.
The more pernicious problem occurs when it's used in a fractional-N loop. Then not just the metastability, but also the race condition in the logic, results in a slight non-linearity in the loop output, causing demodulation of the high frequency frac-N components down into baseband, where they can pass through the loop filter, and modulate the carrier with spurious low frequency tones.
This is why the highest quality fractional PLLs use a 4-state PSD rather than the 3-state you have shown. Patent now expired, so free to use by anybody, commercial or otherwise.

Thanks for your answer, @Neil_UK. Sorry that I was not clear in describing the context of my question. The PLL-related diagrams is a bit misleading, although my current question is not related to PLL scenarios. I updated my post trying to clarify my intent. Thanks again!

You are directing your question to adjustment of sampling point via a phase rotator. That's basically the same as a PLL. Any errors caused by metstability will be averaged out by the low pass effect of however the sampling point is adjusted.
